# React router push only changes the url

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm using react router and I would like to redirect to a detailed page on a click on a row.

Here is my component

```
<Table
  model={TypeModel}
  source={this.props.types}
  selectable={false}
  onRowClick={index => this.context.router.push(`/dashboard/types/${this.props.types[index].id}`)}
/>
```

On click the url the changed, but my page remains the same. I defined the routes like this

```
{
  path: '/dashboard',
  component: requireAuthentication(DashboardLayout),
  indexRoute: Dashboard,
  childRoutes: [{
    path: 'types',
    indexRoute: TypeListRoute(store),
    childRoutes: [
      TypeDetailsRoute(store) // The path of this route is :id
    ]
  }]
}
```

I can not find why, this is working everywhere else in the application. I also checked and tried this threads

- [browserhistory-push-doesnt-navigate-to-new-page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35526825/browserhistory-push-doesnt-navigate-to-new-page)
- [react-router-push-only-changes-the-url-and-does-not-navigate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37753359/react-router-push-only-changes-the-url-and-does-not-navigate)
- [programmatically-navigate-using-react-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31079081/programmatically-navigate-using-react-router)

Did I miss something ?

---

## More details

My router looks like

```
const routes = createRoutes(store)
<Router history={browserHistory} children={routes} />
```

with the following `createRoutes` method

```
createRoutes = store => ({
  childRoutes: [{
    path: '/',
    component: HomeLayout,
    indexRoute: Home,
    childRoutes: [
      LoginRoute(store),
      LogoutRoute(store),
      SignupRoute(store)
    ]
  }, {
    path: '/dashboard',
    component: requireAuthentication(DashboardLayout),
    indexRoute: Dashboard,
    childRoutes: [
      DeviceRoute(store),
      UserRoute(store),
      {
        path: 'types',
        indexRoute: TypeListRoute(store),
        childRoutes: [
          TypeDetailsRoute(store)
        ]
      }
    ]
  }]
})
```

The `DashboardLayout` is a react component that wrap children into some components

```
export class DashboardLayout extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.children = props.children
  }

  render () {
    return ( 
      <Layout theme={drawerTheme}>
        <NavDrawer pinned >...</NavDrawer>
        <Panel>
          {this.children}
        </Panel>
      </Layout>
    )
  }
}
```

The `TypeListRoute` looks like

```
export const TypeListRoute = store => ({
  getComponent (nextState, cb) {
    require.ensure([], (require) => {
      const Type = require('./containers/TypeContainer').default

      const reducer = require('./modules/type').default

      injectReducer(store, { key: 'type', reducer })

      cb(null, Type)
    }, 'type')
  }
})
```

where `TypeContainer` returns a connected (to redux store) `Table` from 'react-toolbox`

`TypeDetailsRoute` is quite the same, but I specified a path

```
export const TypeDetailsRoute = store => ({
  path: ':id',
  getComponent (nextState, cb) {
    require.ensure([], (require) => {
      const Type = require('./containers/TypeDetailsContainer').default

      const reducer = require('./modules/type').default

      injectReducer(store, { key: 'type', reducer })

      cb(null, Type)
    }, 'type')
  }
})
```

Here `TypeDetailsContainer` return s something completely different thant a `Table`. I tried with a simple `h1` and I still have the error

Comment: I see you are async loading reducers and probably using `store.replaceReducer`. Is that working fine? I mean I used to see similar behaviour; the route changes but the new page doesn't render because replacing reducer went wrong and threw some error in my console. :)

Comment: It seems to work fine. It is working with other routes and I have not a single error in the console

Comment: do you have a github link of the entire project?

Comment: I'm afraid no, this is a company project and I have no rights to share it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it !!!

In the `createRoutes` method, I have to change the root `childRoutes` by its asynchronous version `getChildRoutes`.

So the `createRoutes` method becomes (`TypeRoute` regroups both `TypeListRoute` and `TypeDetailRoute`)

```
export const createRoutes = store => ({
  getChildRoutes (nextState, cb) {
    cb(null, [{
      path: '/',
      component: HomeLayout,
      indexRoute: Home,
      childRoutes: [
        LoginRoute(store),
        LogoutRoute(store),
        SignupRoute(store)
      ]
    }, {
      path: '/dashboard',
      component: requireAuthentication(DashboardLayout),
      indexRoute: Dashboard,
      childRoutes: [
        DeviceRoute(store),
        UserRoute(store),
        TypeRoute(store)
      ]
    }])
  }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Link` component to accomplish this:

```
import { Link } from 'react-router'

...

<Link to={`/dashboard/types/${this.props.types[index].id}`}>Dashboard page</Link>
```

Comment: I'm using `react-toolbox` `Table` component, so I don't know if I can change all rows by a `Link`. Is there an equivalent method that can be called ?

Comment: It seems that the `Link` component is using the `push` method also ([sources](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/modules/Link.js))

Comment: @ThomasThiebaud can you update the question with the components being rendered from the `<Router>`. If the URL is changing but the page visually isn't updating, then it's likely that React is saying "nothing has changed, no re-rendering necessary". So I don't think it has anything to do with the routes (your method should work fine).

Comment: I added more details into my questions